# Incorporating Bootstrap 4 to an existing REACT project

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a question about incorporating Bootstrap 4 to an existing REACT project.

Following the instructions on BootStrap website: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/

I tried to incorporate BootStrap4 to my project by downloading the BootStrap source files into my project folder and including it in index.html

INDEX.HTML
[image]

When I try to get a button function on index.js, it is not shown formatted with BootStrap 4.

INDEX.JS
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? I searched for a while and could not find the answer. The console does not display errors and npm shows compiled successfully.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Shouldn't `class="btn btn-primary"` be `className="btn btnprimary"` ? 'Class' is a reserved word

Comment: YES! That's it! Thank you so much